# Applying forces to move spaceship without torque

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm building a game prototype where you **control a 2D spaceship by activating it's thrusters**.

Below is an schema of my thruster. It applies a force in the direction of the arrow, with a variable and controlled intensity.

[image]

Now let's assume I have the following blue spaceship, with 6 attached thrusters:

[image]

Currently I can fly it by activating the following thrusters:

- 1 to move forward
- 2 and 5 to steer left
- 3 and 6 to steer right

---

Now I would like to implement an alternative way of flying:

**Given a direction**, let's say upwards, I would like to **move the spaceship in that direction without applying torque**.

How can I achieve that? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

---

I believe it's possible with the right combination of thruster activations with variable intensities.

I apologise if my question doesn't meet the criteria or standards of the forum.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: if you apply torque about the y axis , where y is locate at the center of mass perpendicular to the axis $\vec R_{14}$ your spaceship will go upwards or downwards (elevation) together with the force an point 1 your spaceship will go forwards

Comment: Do you want the spaceship's longitudinal axis determined by thrusters 1 and 4 to point always in the direction of the motion, or flying "sideways" is enough? Because if you want the orientation to be respected, you would always need to apply some torque at some point, at least to give the spacecraft some initial angular velocity, in order to reorient the axis. Without torque, the center of mass would move in the proper direction but the longitudinal axis will be pointing in a direction different from the direction of the motion (that's why I used the term "sideways" motion).

Answer (score 1):

If the lines of thrust for thrusters $2$ and $3$ are the same perpendicular distance from the centre of mass of the spaceship then you can go sideways with no torque using equal thrust from $2$ and $3$. Then to go, for example, $45^o$ to the right of forward you use thrust $T$ from $1$ and thrust $\frac T 2$ from $2$ and $3$.

If the lines of thrust for thrusters $2$ and $3$ are not the same perpendicular distance from the centre of mass then you need to make the thrust from each thruster inversely proportional to its perpendicular distance so that the thrusters produce equal but opposite moments.

Comment: I think there is one caveat, which is that this approach, just by itself, is not going to reorient the longitudinal axis of the spaceship to point in the direction of the motion, if initially the rocket doesn't have angular velocity. This method will take care of the center of mass, but the orientation of the rocket relative to the direction of motion will be a bit weird. To reorient the longitudinal axis, one always needs to include some torque at some time.